# How to make underlined-centered titles at KOMA-script?

Tags: sectioning, koma-script

So I tried to make underlined-centered titles:
The answer for the centered came [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/479616/29476) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/479683/29476).

Now my question is, how I make it underlined: with `\ul` it doesn't work (the file don't compile, and with `uline` I get ugly underline:
[image]

And here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{fontspec,adforn,ulem,soul}

\makeatletter

\addtokomafont{section}{\centering}  
\addtokomafont{subsection}{\centering}
\renewcommand{\sectionlinesformat}[4]{%
    %\@tempswafalse
        \ifstr{#1}{section}{%
                {\@hangfrom{{{#3}{#4}\adforn{12}}}}
        }
        {\ifstr{#1}{subsection}{%
                {\@hangfrom{\uline{{{#3}{#4}\adforn{24}}}}}%
        }
    {\@hangfrom{\hskip#2#3}{#4}}}%
}\makeatother

\begin{document}

\part{ABC}

\section{abc}

\subsection{abcd efgh abcd efgh iiii hhjjgghgg abcd efgh abcd efgh iiii hhjjgghgg abcd efgh abcd efgh iiii hhjjgghgg}
\end{document}
```

P.S. For the parts I got answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/458172/29476) but it also don't work.
and here is about using [`\ul` or `\uline`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9550/why-does-underlined-text-not-get-wrapped-once-it-hits-the-end-of-a-line/9552#9552).
And if I'm putting `parbox` this what I get:
[image]
and this is the relevant line:

```
{\ifstr{#1}{subsection}{%
                {\@hangfrom{\uline{\parbox{\linewidth}{{#3}{#4}\adforn{24}}}}}%
        }
```

Do you have any idea how it could work and look properly and the text can be more then one line centered and underlined?

Thank you!!

Comment: Your usage of `\@hangfrom` is wrong and does not make sense. Do you known, what it does? You should remove it and several of the brace-pairs too. Off-topic: Underlining is ugly and AFAIK there are no perfect solutions to do it with LaTeX.

Comment: @Schweinebacke, I will remove it, I take it from KOMA-script manual. And why there is no solution? can you think about something do similar? Thanks!

Comment: All underlines are ugly. If you don't *have* to underline, don't do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To visualize the problems with underlining in your case please see the following code. It is based [on my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/479616/16550) and uses underlining with command `\ul{}` from package `soul`. 
Please see also that your used `\adforn{}` is placed in the title for section and subsection:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{fontspec,adforn}
\usepackage{soul}


\begin{document}

\renewcommand\raggedsection{\centering}

\part{ABC}

\section{\ul{abc test test test test test test test test test test test test 
  test test test test test test test test test test test test test test 
  test test test test test test} \adforn{12}} % <=======================

\subsection{\ul{def} \adforn{24}} % <===================================

\section{\ul{abc test test test test test test test test test test test test 
  test test test test test test test test test test test test test test 
  test test test test test test \protect\adforn{12}}} % <===============
\end{document}
```

with the result:

[image]

As you can see `\ul{...}` is able to underline long text inside a `\section` if the `\adforn{}` **is not included** to `\ul` (see first red circle in image above)!

Now you can try to include `\adforn` into `\ul` like

```
\subsection{\ul{def \adforn{24}}}
```

with the result of 9 errors.

As you can see marked with the second red circle in the image above you can use `\protect\adfarn` to be able to compile without errors but the result is ugly (second red circle).

**Conclusion:**

- You can have underlining with centering without using `\adforn` or
- you can use `\adforn` with centering but without underlining

I suggest to omit underlining!

Based [on the second MWE in this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/479683/16550) you can do

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{adforn}
\usepackage{soul} % <===================================================

\renewcommand\raggedsection{\centering}

\let\originalsectionlinesformat\sectionlinesformat
\renewcommand{\sectionlinesformat}[4]{%
  \originalsectionlinesformat{#1}{#2}{#3}{\ul{#4}% <====================
    \ifstr{#1}{section}{\adforn{12}}
      {\ifstr{#1}{subsection}{\adforn{24}}{}}%
  }%
}

\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text
\begin{document}
\section{abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc}
\blindtext
\subsection{def}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

to get underlining heading for `\section` and `\subsection` without automaticly added `\adforn` symbol. **But see: that could result in ugly typography**, depending on the content of the used heading text ...

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But if I want that the `adforn` symbols will be part of the title automatically, and not manually, can I do it? Or it's a problem? (because as you can see, it was at the MWE...) Thank you!!

Comment: @heblyx see the second mwe of the answer here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/479683/16550 ... But be careful: Things can go wrong if the headings for section and subsection contains non-ascii-letters, they can result simular errors `\adforn` does ... You want to force underlining, but believe me (and the others telling you) it is a bad idea.

Comment: Saw it... So I can make only the text (without the `adforn`) underlined? (and centered of course...)

Comment: It's possible??

Comment: Yes... This what I tried right now but it's still not working :-( It's still one long line.... Do you not what can I do??
Thank you!!